# Why not in ignores null?

Tags: sql

Please look into the below tsql script

```
declare @t table(x varchar(50) null)
insert into @t values(null),('Y'),('N'),('WOFF')
select *
from @t t
where t.x not in ('WOFF')
```

the output is

```
Y
N
```

But expected is

```
NULL
Y
N
```

What is wrong in the sql script?

Comment: Because NULL is not equal or unequal to anything. You have to use `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL`. `NULL` basically means unknown/undefined, how database could know if an unknown/undefined value is unequal to `WOFF`?

Comment: Welcome to [Three-Valued logic in SQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_(SQL)#Comparisons_with_NULL_and_the_three-valued_logic_.283VL.29)

Comment: The expected result is wrong, the current result is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you may need to do this:

```
declare @t table(x varchar(50) null)
insert into @t values(null),('Y'),('N'),('WOFF')
select *
from @t t
where t.x not in ('WOFF') or t.x is null
```

or

```
declare @t table(x varchar(50) null)
insert into @t values(null),('Y'),('N'),('WOFF')
select *
from @t t
where t.x not in ('WOFF') or t.x is not null
```

Comment: or `where ISNULL(t.x,'null') not in ('WOFF')`

Answer (score 2):

Because there's going to be a check for equality when you run the query and WOFF is a value, while null is an indication of no-value.
And of course no-value cannot be equal to any value.

Answer (score 1):

`NULL` is ignored in all conditions except `IS NULL`. Something like `0` in Roulette :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe null is officially designated as "unknown value" This means you cannot resolve it with regular true false checks.

In your example you want to know which values are not woff. As null is `unknown` as far as the compiler is concerned it could be woff or it could not be woff unfortunately it can't prove either way and so is programmed to ignore it - it is better to accidentally leave out a potentially correct answer than to return potentially incorrect anser.

Therefore you need to include specific checks such as value `is null` or value `is not null` as other answers have suggested. This then changes your statement to return all values that are not woff or that are unknown

Answer (score 0):

Use below query :

```
 SELECT CASE WHEN x = 'Y' THEN 'Y' WHEN x = 'N' THEN 'N' END
 FROM @t t
 WHERE t.x NOT IN ('WOFF') OR t.x IS NULL
```

Comment: What is the idea in `CASE WHEN x = 'Y' THEN 'Y' WHEN x = 'N' THEN 'N' END` - I cannot understand? The `CASE` statement is equivalent to simple single letter `x`.